# Double Value To Hex Value in C

Tags: c

I need to convert double value to hex value;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
uint64_t DoubleToHexCoverter(double f);

int main()
{
    a = 40.123456789;
    printf("Hex: %08x",DoubleToHexCoverter(a));

    return 0;
}

uint64_t DoubleToHexCoverter(double d)
{
  return (*(unsigned int*)&d);
}
```

I get this result:

```
Hex: 000000006e9b9cb2
```

I see half of the numbers. Other's full with zeros "00000000" How can I get all numbers correctly.
I think uint64 value's keeping 32 bit + 32 bit values but I didnt do that please help me.

When I try below codes I get same result.
**EDIT:**

```
uint64_t DoubleToHexCoverter(double f)
{
  return (*(uint64_t*)&f);
}
```

Comment: That's a violation of strict-aliasing, so it's undefined behavior (Also, I doubt `unsigned int` would ever be as large as a `double`).

Comment: Why don't you simply use `printf("Hex: %08x",static_cast<unsigned int> (a));`? (Provided that it is not larger, than the max. integer)

Comment: Why not cast to `uint64_t*` provided that you want `uint64_t`?

Comment: @MikeCAT I've already try but answer is same I get 000000006e9b9cb2

Comment: btw, `%08x` probably should be `%08llx`

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to print the binary *representation* of the floating-point number, or are you trying to print the value in hex notation?

If it's the latter, just use the `%a` or `%A` conversions:

```
printf( "Hex: %a\n", a );
```

giving us

```
Hex:   0x1.40fcd6e9b9cb2p+5
```

If you want to print the binary representation of the number, a "safe" way of doing it is:

```
union rep
{
  double a;
  unsigned char bytes[ sizeof (double) ];
};

union rep r = {.a = 40.123456789 };

fputs( "Bytes: ", stdout );

for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof r.a; i++ )
  printf( "%02hhx ", r.bytes[i] );
putchar( '\n' );
```

giving us

```
Bytes: b2 9c 9b 6e cd 0f 44 40
```

Since I'm on x86 which is little-endian, those bytes are ordered from *least* significant to *most* significant, so `b2` represents the lowest 8 bytes of the value - it should actually be read as

```
40440fcd6e9b9cb2
```

Comment: Ooh, I just understood now what the question was :-)

Comment: @Laci - I didn't, which is why I presented both options.  And there's no guarantee I answered the OP's actual question.

Answer (score 1):

You want `uint64_t`, so you should cast to `uint64_t*`, not `unsigned int*`.

```
uint64_t DoubleToHexCoverter(double d)
{
  return (*(unsigned int*)&d);
}
```

Also using `%x` for printing `uint64_t` invokes *undefined behavior* because it is wrong type for `%x`, which expects `unsigned int`.

You should add `#include <inttypes.h>` and use `PRIx64` macro like `"%" PRIx64` to print `uint64_t`.

This may work in the real world, but this violates [the strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) and the behavior is not guaranteed. You can use [`memcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) to copy bytes from objects to objects.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

uint64_t DoubleToHexCoverter(double d)
{
  uint64_t res;
  assert(sizeof(uint64_t) == sizeof(double));
  memcpy(&res, &d, sizeof(d));
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Probably a better idea to have a `static_assert` as opposed to an `assert`.

Comment: @MikeCAT thank you for your response butI get same result again, https://onlinegdb.com/tFmx7ojR_

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the appropriate length specifier for the printf() function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
uint64_t DoubleToHexCoverter(double f);

int main()
{
    double a = 40.123456789;
    printf("\nHex: %zx", DoubleToHexCoverter(a));

    return 0;
}

uint64_t DoubleToHexCoverter(double d)
{
  return (*(uint64_t*)&d);
}
```

I used the length specifier "z" from here:
https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

With that code i get the output:

```
Hex: 40440fcd6e9b9cb2
```